# Any benefits for using fields as opposed to properties

Tags: entities

I have a module that pulls data constantly from an external source, from up to thousands of different items with over 50 properties.

The data is being collected every 15 minutes.

The problem is that writing each property to a Drupal field seems to take a great deal of time - so many joins. It seems like it would be more efficient to save these values as properties on the entity.

Is there any downside to doing that? What are the strengths and weaknesses of keeping everything a property on the entity table rather than making each one a field?